# Время работы скрипта на Python

Tags: python, время

Как я могу сделать определенное время работы скрипта(30 секунд?)

Скрипт должен запуститься и через 30 секунд прекратить свою работу.

Answer (score 0):

Если скрипт должен делать только то, что Вы описали в вопросе, вот Вам такой скрипт:

```py
import time
time.sleep(30)
```

Если же ждать и завершать нужно при выполнении какой-то другой задачи, то можно сделать так:

```py
import time
import sys
import threading

def wait_and_stop(sec):
    time.sleep(sec)
    sys.exit(0)

t = threading.Thread(target = wait_and_stop, args = (1,))
t.start()

# Здесь код основной задачи, прерываемой по истечении 30ти секунд (т.е. Ваш скрипт)
```

Здесь по истечении 30ти секунд выполнение всех инструкций прервётся и будет произведено завершение программы.

Comment: Он приостанавливает, а не завершает

Comment: Вы сами пробовали запускать этот код?

Comment: @andreymal Конечно, у меня работает

Comment: А я вот вместо «Ваш скрипт» написал реальный код с вечным циклом, а он у меня не остановился и продолжил работать до бесконечности. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: @andreymal Хммм, при бесконечном цикле и правда не выходит...

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю запустить в отдельном процессе и убить его через определённое время.

***Пример:***

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep


def func() -> None:
    while True:
        print('Work...')
        sleep(1)


def main() -> None:
    p = Process(target=func)
    p.start()

    sleep(5)
    p.terminate()
    # Продолжение скрипта


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Данный скрипт будет выполнять функцию `func` `5` секунд, после чего прервёт её выполнение.
Подставьте вместо `func` Ваш скрипт, а аргумент, передаваемый `sleep` в функции `main` измените на необходимое время, например, `30`.

Comment: Мне не нужно завершать весь процесс. Мне нужно завершить исполнение функции.

Comment: @Nikita Тогда это хороший вариант. Просто продолжите программу после инструкции `p.terminate()`

Comment: @Nikita Тогда Вы некорректно задали вопрос. У Вас речь идёт обо всём скрипте, а не о конкретной функции. Лучшим вариантом будет задать новый вопрос насчёт функции, т.к. уже были даны ответы на вопрос про скрипт.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Решение сильно зависит от "скрипта". Но вот еще пример:

```
import sys
from time import time, sleep


start_time = time()

while time() - start_time < 30.:
    print("Выполняюсь")
    sleep(1)

print("Выполнение завершено.")
sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно выполнять какую-то процедуру циклически, то используйте модуль `time`:

```
import time

max_time = 3 # время, через которое нужно остановиться, в секундах
start_time = time.time()  # запоминаем время старта

while (time.time() - start_time) < max_time:
    print("do something") # выполняемый код
```